# Role based and User based XACML policy

Tags: authorization, xacml, xacml3, abac, wso2-identity-server

Let me explain my problem using an example -

Suppose, I have root location Mumbai (root element of location hierarchy ) and two child Andheri and Bandra.

I have two roles - Manager and plant engineer. Manager have access to all the location comes under Mumbai and plant engineer have child level access of root element(Mumbai).

I have four employee, employee "A" as a manager, employee "B", "C" and "D" as a plant engineer.

Since "B", "C" and "D" are plant engineer, so all three have access to Andheri and Bandra level location but i want to apply condition through my XACML policy that plant engineer "B" and "D" should have privilege to access only Andheri location and plant engineer "C" should have privilege to access both Andheri and Bandra location.

I am not getting how should i write XACML policy, which can satisfy my above given condition.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood, it looks like you already have role based XACML policy which works fine for "Manager" and "Plant Engineer" roles but you need to have additional check to allow limited access to the locations as per user.

Now you should not create policy based on username as it would be diffcult to maintain as users keep changing and removed/deactivated from system especially in case of employees.
Now better way I suggest is to have an additional attribute in user profile e.g. "allowedLocation" whose value could be "Andheri" or "Bandra" and you can have a XACML policy which will check if accessed resource (i.e. plant is "Andheri" or "Bandra") is equal to user attribute value "allowedLocation" then allow access.

In this case you can either make one policy per Plant or you can create a single generic policy with two rules i.e.

- Rule 1 : if accessed resource = value of user attribute
  "allowedLocation" then "Allow"
- Rule 2 : Else "Deny"